# How to produce an iphone app which calculates the battery status?

Tags: iphone, power-management

How to produce an iphone app which calculates the battery status? Is there a particular API that i need to use?

Has anyone got a link to any online tutorials?

Answer (score 3):

Just set `[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES`.  Then you can use `-[UIDevice batteryState]` and `-[UIDevice batteryLevel]`.

Comment: Don't forget to call `currentDevice` for `batteryLevel` too though.